# how to ask user to enter valid details in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

may i know how to ask user to give correct input in Dialogflow...
for example if user has to enter a number between 1-100 numbers but he entered a value exceeding that limit. how to verify it using Webhooks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show what code you've used in the webhook and what isn't working?

Comment: @Prisoner If user enters a valid Ticket number i'm returning `{                      speech: 'Your tickets are confirmed..!',  displayText: 'Here you go..!',               'data': {'facebook': {'attachment': {'type': 'template','payload': {                  'template_type': 'list', 'top_element_style': 'compact',   'elements': o.elements }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }` ,                  how to ask user to enter a valid ticket number if user not entered a valid ticket number?

Comment: Please update your question - don't try to post code in the comments, since they're very difficult to read. Do you have an example of what your webhook looks like when it handles a valid ticket? Do you try to do anything when it is an invalid ticket?